# Giving a Window form application Transparent effect just like window 7 in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I know how to make the form transparent by using 
this:
Opacity and then its value... but that make's the whole form transparent! 
I want my form outer body to be transparent not that application content.

**For Example:**

**In window 7 their is a transparent effect which user can see throught the appliction and at the same time the appliction inner contents remain Non-Transparent making the application Click Able !

Answer (score 1):

The effect you are after is Aero glass, which is only available since Vista, and must be enabled on the system. There is some more info here about how to control the behavour through managed code using `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea`.

http://www.thecodeking.co.uk/2007/02/windows-vista-aero-glass-in-net-managed.html

Comment: where can i find this dll file which you used in your appliction demo ?  DLL 'dwmapi.dll

Comment: You need Vista or Windows 7, it's not possible with XP or older versions of Windows.